# Object doesnt support this property or method in VBA with SortFields referencing Object

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, object

I am trying to reference this below function in the Tab which has all the questions numbers linked into another tab which has all the question numbers. I am creating a scorecard in complete different tab with this function and when I click the button Create Scorecard it pops up the message that 'Object doesnt support this property or method'

I am using excel version 2016 so confused if any of the function doesnt working in the version or code has the problem?

I have written whole code in the Comment section since it was not allowing me to enter into body. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaRVb.png)

```
Sub A_CreateQuestion() 
Dim i, j, k As Integer 
Dim irow, icol, urow, ucol, ipat, iboo, upat, uboo, inam, unam As String 
Application.DisplayAlerts = False 
Application.CutCopyMode = False 
Sheets("Scorecard Build").Activate 
irow = Range("A65583").End(xlUp).Row 

If Cells(1, 14) <> "" Then Cells(2, 1).Copy Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(irow, 1)) 
For j = irow To 2 Step -1 
If Cells(j, 1) = "" Then Rows(j).Delete xlUp 
Next 
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Scorecard Build").ListObjects("SB").Sort. _ SortFields.Clear ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Scorecard Build").ListObjects("SB").Sort. _ 
SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("SB[[#All],[Item '#]]"), SortOn:= _ xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Scorecard Build").ListObjects("SB").Sort  

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Scorecard Build").ListObjects("SB").Sort. _ SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("SB[[#All],[Item '#]]"), SortOn:= _ xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Scorecard Build").ListObjects("SB").Sort .Header = xlYes .MatchCase = False .Orientation = xlTopToBottom .SortMethod = xlPinYin .Apply End
```

Comment: Sub A_CreateQuestion()


Dim i, j, k As Integer
Dim irow, icol, urow, ucol, ipat, iboo, upat, uboo, inam, unam As String


Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.CutCopyMode = False


Sheets("Scorecard Build").Activate
irow = Range("A65583").End(xlUp).Row

Comment: If Cells(1, 14) <> "" Then
    Cells(2, 1).Copy Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(irow, 1))
    For j = irow To 2 Step -1
        If Cells(j, 1) = "" Then Rows(j).Delete xlUp
    Next
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Scorecard Build").ListObjects("SB").Sort. _
            SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Scorecard Build").ListObjects("SB").Sort. _
        SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("SB[[#All],[Item '#]]"), SortOn:= _
        xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Scorecard Build").ListObjects("SB").Sort

Comment: ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Scorecard Build").ListObjects("SB").Sort. _
        SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("SB[[#All],[Item '#]]"), SortOn:= _
        xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Scorecard Build").ListObjects("SB").Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

Comment: Please *edit your post* if you want to add code.  https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76560405/edit

Comment: @TimWilliams I am not able to add code in the code function provided in the body. Thats why posted in the comment and as wells as posted a picture of it

Comment: There's no problem pasting code into the post - see for example all the other posts on this site...

Comment: It shows error- Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

Comment: Would you be able to take a look at the image that I have uploaded of the code and can able to suggest where its going wrong or what edits I need to do ?

Comment: I made a start for you - please continue the formatting, and let us know which line has the error.

Comment: Thank you so much Tim!!

This line has error: 

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Scorecard Build").ListObjects("SB").Sort. _ 
SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("SB[[#All],[Item '#]]"), SortOn:= _ xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

Comment: `Key:=Range("SB[[#All],[Item '#]]")` should probably be `Key:=Range("SB[Item '#]")`

Comment: Thank you Tim !! What does [#All] function denotes? Also by removing [#All] would it still consider all the ranges that haven been defined?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/using-structured-references-with-excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e#:~:text=The%20entire%20table%2C%20including%20column%20headers%2C%20data%2C%20and%20totals%20(if%20any).

Answer (score 0):

In the problem line:

`Key:=Range("SB[[#All],[Item '#]]")`

should probably be

`Key:=Range("SB[Item '#]")`